# Convert Owner field from Picklist to contact look-up in Professional Edition

Tags: professional-edition

I am Using **Professional Edition** . In my Lead object there is a field name as SDR Owner( which is Pick-list) currently and in this there are 5-6 values. I want to convert it into Contact Look UP. How to achieve this. ?

Please help  me  out .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below steps.

1. Create Contact record for every single picklist value
2. Create Another field with Contact Lookup
3. Using the dataloader or trigger to update your historical data with corresponding contact record id.
4. Delete your picklist field and start using your new Contact lookup field.

**P.S. As data loader is not available in PE edition you can use external tool such as [Excel Connector](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector) or [SimpleImport](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009x6YDEAY) or [Import 2](http://www.import2.com/salesforce/new)**

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But in Professional Edition there is no Dataloader and  Triggers .

Comment: I didn't notice edition. please check updated answer